# How do I make this Javascript code dry and efficient?

Tags: javascript, dry

```
const secretNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
console.log(secretNumber);
let playerGuess = 0;
let turns = 1;

function guessNumber(guess, num) {
  for (let tries = 5; tries > 0; tries--) {
    if (guess < num && tries < 5) {
      console.log(`Too low. Guess Again`);
      turns++;
    } else if (guess > num && tries < 5) {
      console.log(`Too high. Guess Again`);
      turns++;
    } else if (guess === num && tries > 1) {
      console.log(`You're a Winner baby, in ${turns} tries!`);
      break;
    }
    guess = Number(prompt('Guess a number tween 0 and 10.'));
  }

  if (guess !== num && turns == 5) {
    console.log(`You're a Loser bub, no more guesses!`);
  }

  if (guess == num && turns == 5) {
    console.log(`You're a Winner baby, in ${turns} tries!`);
  }
}

guessNumber(playerGuess, secretNumber);
```

So my code works, feel free to run in it in the console, but I know it could definitely be more dry and efficient. I just don't know how to make this any simpler. How do I write more efficient and dry code?

Comment: Since the code in your question is working, it's off-topic for StackOverflow. The best fit for it would be [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for code that *doesn't* work. Code reviews should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ after reading their [help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) and [faq](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes) pages

Answer (score 1):

I would change the code a bit and make it working.

Currently, it does not show the user the result of the guess and presents only
a promt for input without further information. This is leveraged to the console.

Here are the changes:

- No global variables. Keep all necessary random values and counter inside of the function, Delete the variable `guess`, because it has no function.
- Omit parameters of the function. If necessary, you could take a parameter for having a handover of a max value for the random number.
- Use another variable for a hint.
- Take only one variable for loop and counting, Increment that value until the wanted maximum iteration is reached.
- Take a local constant variable for the guess, show the hint with prompt.
- Then it follows some comparisons with `guess` and `secretNumer`. If they are the same, show the message *win* and exit the function. For all others, adjust `hint` and `continue`.
- Finally, if this part is reached, the user has lost.

```js
function guessNumber() {
    const secretNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log(secretNumber);
    let hint = '';
    for (let turns = 1; turns <= 5; turns++) {
        const guess = Number(prompt(hint + 'Guess a number tween 0 and 10.'));

        if (guess === secretNumber) {
            console.log(`You're a Winner baby, in ${turns} tries!`);
            return;
        }

        if (guess < secretNumber) {
            hint = 'Too low. ';
            continue;
        }

        if (guess > secretNumber) {
            hint = 'Too high. ';
        }
    }

    console.log('You have lost, no more guesses!');
}

guessNumber();
```